# how to fill values to one single column efficiently in excel file using pywin32?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I know that I could fill rows using a source in an array using Pywin32 like

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
ws.Range("A4:D4").Value = [i for i in range(1,5)]
```

But in single column case, When I try this like

```
ws.Range("A1:A4").Value = [i for i in range(1,5)]
```

I got four 1 in column 'A', but what I wanted is 1, 2, 3, 4 in column 'A'

Is there similar way to deal with column?

If no, what's the most efficient way to fill multiple cells once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
ws.Range("A1:A4").Value = [[i] for i in range(1,5)]
```

What you did before was try to fit [1, 2, 3, 4] into a column. However, when it gets converted to the excel formatting an array is always converted into a row. So when you create a 2D array you create an array of rows which is how excel views a column. So what you want is [[1],[2],[3],[4]]. Which is what the code above generates.

EDIT: I realize this may not be the best wording in the world. If you don't get it just ask and I will try to come up with a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks! "ws.Range("A1:A4").Value = [[i] for i in range(1,5)]" This solved it for me "[[i] for i in range(1,5)]".

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for col_idx, i in enumerate(xrange(1,5)):
    ws.Cells(1, col_idx+1).Value = i
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know this way. But is it efficient if the column is ver long?

Comment: Either way you've got a `for` loop.